# Routing in ASP.NET MVC, showing username in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying to make a route so I can show the username in the URL like this:

http://localhost1234/john

Here Is my routeconfig:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "users", // Route name
                url: "{username}", // URL with parameters
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", username = "" } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Here is my HomeController:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string username = "Test")
 {
   return View();
  }
```

First of all, the URL Is not changed. When I set `username = "Test"` inside my route-config, the URL is not changed.

Second, I can't navigate to my other controllers. If I change the URL to http://localhost123/Welcome, nothing happens. It should redirect me to a new page.

What am I doing wrong here?

If I change the order of the routes, I can navigate to other pages, but the username Is not displayed In the URL.

I have googled and all of the answers on this subject says that I should use a route like the one above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change route to username after logged in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996021/how-to-change-route-to-username-after-logged-in)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On its own, your routing will not work because if the url was `.../Product` meaning that you wanted to navigate to the `Index()` method of `ProductController`, it would match your first route (and assume "Product" is the `username`. You need to add a route constraint to your roue definitions that returns `true` if the `username` is valid and `false` if not (in which case it will try the following routes to find a match).

Assuming you have a `UserController` with the following methods

```
// match http://..../Bryan
public ActionResult Index(string username)
{
    // displays the home page for a user
}

// match http://..../Bryan/Photos
public ActionResult Photos(string username)
{
    // displays a users photos
}
```

Then you route definitions need to be

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "User",
            url: "{username}",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Index" },
            constraints: new { username = new UserNameConstraint() }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "UserPhotos",
            url: "{username}/Photos",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Photos" },
            constraints: new { username = new UserNameConstraint() }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }

    public class UserNameConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            List<string> users = new List<string>() { "Bryan", "Stephen" };
            // Get the username from the url
            var username = values["username"].ToString().ToLower();
            // Check for a match (assumes case insensitive)
            return users.Any(x => x.ToLower() == username);
        }
    }
}
```

If the url is `.../Bryan`, it will match the `User` route and you will execute the `Index()` method in `UserController` (and the value of `username` will be `"Bryan"`)

If the url is `.../Stephen/Photos`, it will match the `UserPhotos` route and you will execute the `Photos()` method in `UserController` (and the value of `username` will be `"Stephen"`)

If the url is `.../Product/Details/4`, then the route constraint will return false for the first 2 route definitions and you will execute the `Details()` method of `ProductController`

If the url is `.../Peter` or `.../Peter/Photos` and there is no user with `username = "Peter"` then it will return `404 Not Found`

Note that the the sample code above hard codes the users, but in reality you will call a service that returns a collection containing the valid user names. To avoid hitting the database each request, you should consider using `MemoryCache` to cache the collection. The code would first check if it exists, and if not populate it, then check if the collection contains the `username`. You would also need to ensure that the cache was invalidated if a new user was added.

Comment: If I could upvote this twice I would. I keep forgetting about the constraint and feel foolish when ever I realize that. My mind immediately jumps to the crazy hack I had to do ages ago, which when ever I look back at it in hind sight is being over thought.

Comment: Exactly what I needed and gave good advice on future use, even the MemoryCache part, well done!

Answer (score 1):

You need to categorize the url for different section of your website so that url pattern matching mechanism go smooth. For example in your case put a category 'profile'  or anything other. Now your request url look like http://localhost1234/profile/john and route will be

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "users", // Route name
                url: "Profile/{username}", // URL with parameters
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
            );

 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

For more information follow link [Routing in MVC](http://www.niceonecode.com/Q-A/DotNet/MVC/routing-in-mvc-4/20190)

Comment: And If I don't want to categorize? Have a look at facebook. When you are visiting your profile, the url are http://facebook/yourusername

Comment: @Bryan , Actually in above example I preserve this for other static pages like aboutus, constactus. You can do this by removing Profile/ in the route as url: "{username}". In this case any request url in the form domain/abc will search same action for username="abc"