# MVC Routing template to represent infinite self-referential hierarchical category structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have a product category table to represent a hierarchical category structure, a typical `Parent-Child` relationship table in the database.

[image: self-referential category structure]

Fill it with Guitar Center's data as an example:

[image: self-referential category data]

If you render them to a page with `<ul>` and `<li>`:

[image: self-referential category ui]

Texts in blue are the URLs I would like to generate. For any given category, the link consists of its slug and its parents' slugs.

**Note that the example I listed only has 2 parent-child levels. In theory, with the self-referential structure, any child could have infinite parents.**

### Questions:

1. How to set up routing template to achieve that?
2. If the routing template is set up to support that, how to retrieve the leaf category? For example, from the URL `categories/guitars/acoustic-guitars`, I would like to retrieve `acoustic-guitars` as the leaf category, and able to get all products under that `acoustic-guitars` category. Note: I don't want manual parsing on the URL. Ideally it would be the best if the lead category is binded through model binding.

Comment: You making this very difficult for yourself since you will need route constraints otherwise no other routes will work (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358416/routing-in-asp-net-mvc-showing-username-in-url/37359345#37359345) for an example of route constraints). It would be much easier to generate urls such as `../categories/guitars` and `../categories/guitars/acoustic-guitars` in which case it becomes simple

Comment: It would also be much more efficient to search by the ID, so you could generate `../categories/1/guitars` and `../categories/1/guitars/5/acoustic-guitars

Comment: @StephenMuecke: thanks for your comment! 1) Sure I can put `categories` in the URL but my point was to have the leaf category slug plus all its parents' slugs on the URL, and the retrieval of the leaf category. Putting a route constraint or not at the beginning of the URL is irrelevant to my question :). 2) I do not want to expose the categories' identifiers to the public (eve they might not be just integer).

Comment: A route constraint is not irrelevant (without it no other page in you app could be hit) - but the fact you stated _Putting a route constraint or not at the beginning of the URL_ means you do not even understand what a route constraint is!

Comment: And adding the ID's was just a suggestion to make the lookups faster (although I guess you can index the slug fields in the db.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: sorry for my bad English. I just meant of course I need a name before all the category slug chain so that a controller could be called. But I didn't put that detail in my original question because that's irrelevant. And yes, slug will have index constraint on the db.

Comment: Then all you need is a method which is (say) `[Route("categories/{parent}/{child?}")]public ActionResult Categories (string parent, string child)` with route definition for it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I don't think so since you don't know how many parents a child has. For example, a url could be `categories/guitars/acoustic-guitars/6-strings-acoustic-guitars`. In theory it could be infinite levels/depth, even the example I gave on my question only listed 2 levels.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162679/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-david-liang).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to set up routing template to achieve that?

You can't. But you can drop to a lower level and make a data-driven [`IRouter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.irouter?view=aspnetcore-2.0) implementation for CMS-style route management.

### An Example: `CachedRoute<TPrimaryKey>`

Here is an example that tracks and caches a 1-1 mapping of primary key to URL. It is a generic class and I have tested that it works whether the primary key is int or Guid.

There is a pluggable piece that must be injected, `ICachedRouteDataProvider` where the query for the database can be implemented. You also need to supply the controller and action, so this route is generic enough to map multiple database queries to multiple action methods by using more than one instance.

```
public class CachedRoute<TPrimaryKey> : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.IRouter
{
    private readonly string _controller;
    private readonly string _action;
    private readonly ICachedRouteDataProvider<TPrimaryKey> _dataProvider;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    private readonly IRouter _target;
    private readonly string _cacheKey;
    private object _lock = new object();

    public CachedRoute(
        string controller,
        string action,
        ICachedRouteDataProvider<TPrimaryKey> dataProvider,
        IMemoryCache cache,
        IRouter target)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controller))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controller");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(action))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
        if (dataProvider == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dataProvider");
        if (cache == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cache");
        if (target == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("target");

        _controller = controller;
        _action = action;
        _dataProvider = dataProvider;
        _cache = cache;
        _target = target;

        // Set Defaults
        CacheTimeoutInSeconds = 900;
        _cacheKey = "__" + this.GetType().Name + "_GetPageList_" + _controller + "_" + _action;
    }

    public int CacheTimeoutInSeconds { get; set; }

    public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {
        var requestPath = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestPath) && requestPath[0] == '/')
        {
            // Trim the leading slash
            requestPath = requestPath.Substring(1);
        }

        // Get the page id that matches.
        //If this returns false, that means the URI did not match
        if (!GetPageList(context.HttpContext).TryGetValue(requestPath, out TPrimaryKey id))
        {
            return;
        }

        //Invoke MVC controller/action
        var routeData = context.RouteData;

        // TODO: You might want to use the page object (from the database) to
        // get both the controller and action, and possibly even an area.
        // Alternatively, you could create a route for each table and hard-code
        // this information.
        routeData.Values["controller"] = _controller;
        routeData.Values["action"] = _action;

        // This will be the primary key of the database row.
        // It might be an integer or a GUID.
        routeData.Values["id"] = id;

        await _target.RouteAsync(context);
    }

    public VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context)
    {
        VirtualPathData result = null;

        if (TryFindMatch(GetPageList(context.HttpContext), context.Values, out string virtualPath))
        {
            result = new VirtualPathData(this, virtualPath);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private bool TryFindMatch(IDictionary<string, TPrimaryKey> pages, IDictionary<string, object> values, out string virtualPath)
    {
        virtualPath = string.Empty;
        TPrimaryKey id;

        if (!values.TryGetValue("id", out object idObj))
        {
            return false;
        }

        id = SafeConvert<TPrimaryKey>(idObj);
        values.TryGetValue("controller", out object controller);
        values.TryGetValue("action", out object action);

        // The logic here should be the inverse of the logic in 
        // RouteAsync(). So, we match the same controller, action, and id.
        // If we had additional route values there, we would take them all 
        // into consideration during this step.
        if (action.Equals(_action) && controller.Equals(_controller))
        {
            // The 'OrDefault' case returns the default value of the type you're 
            // iterating over. For value types, it will be a new instance of that type. 
            // Since KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> is a value type (i.e. a struct), 
            // the 'OrDefault' case will not result in a null-reference exception. 
            // Since TKey here is string, the .Key of that new instance will be null.
            virtualPath = pages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Equals(id)).Key;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(virtualPath))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private IDictionary<string, TPrimaryKey> GetPageList(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!_cache.TryGetValue(_cacheKey, out IDictionary<string, TPrimaryKey> pages))
        {
            // Only allow one thread to poplate the data
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (!_cache.TryGetValue(_cacheKey, out pages))
                {
                    pages = _dataProvider.GetPageToIdMap(context.RequestServices);

                    _cache.Set(_cacheKey, pages,
                        new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                        {
                            Priority = CacheItemPriority.NeverRemove,
                            AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.CacheTimeoutInSeconds)
                        });
                }
            }
        }

        return pages;
    }

    private static T SafeConvert<T>(object obj)
    {
        if (typeof(T).Equals(typeof(Guid)))
        {
            if (obj.GetType() == typeof(string))
            {
                return (T)(object)new Guid(obj.ToString());
            }
            return (T)(object)Guid.Empty;
        }
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

### CategoryCachedRouteDataProvider

Here we lookup the categories from the database and recursively join the slugs into a URL.

```
public interface ICachedRouteDataProvider<TPrimaryKey>
{
    IDictionary<string, TPrimaryKey> GetPageToIdMap(IServiceProvider serviceProvider);
}

public class CategoryCachedRouteDataProvider : ICachedRouteDataProvider<int>
{
    // NOTE: I wasn't able to figure out how to constructor inject ApplicationDbContext
    // because there doesn't seem to be a way to access the scoped services there,
    // so we are using a service locator here. If someone could let me know how
    // that is done in Startup.Configure() of .NET Core 2.0, please leave a comment.
    public IDictionary<string, int> GetPageToIdMap(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        using (var dbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>())
        {
            // Query the categories so we can build all of the URLs client side
            var categories = dbContext.Categories.ToList();
            var scratch = new StringBuilder();

            return (from category in categories
                    select new KeyValuePair<string, int>(
                        GetUrl(category, categories, scratch),
                        category.CategoryId)
                    ).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
        }
    }

    private string GetUrl(Category category, IEnumerable<Category> categories, StringBuilder result)
    {
        result.Clear().Append(category.Slug);
        while ((category = categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryId == category.ParentCategoryId)) != null)
        {
            result.Insert(0, string.Concat(category.Slug, "/"));
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

### CategoryController

There is nothing special going on in the controller, except for the fact that we don't need to deal with a URL or a slug at this point at all. We simply accept the `id` parameter that maps to the primary key of the record and then you know what to do from there...

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        // Lookup category based on id...

        return View();
    }
}
```

### Usage

We configure this in `Startup.cs` as follows:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddSingleton<CategoryCachedRouteDataProvider>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.Routes.Add(
                new CachedRoute<int>(
                    controller: "Category",
                    action: "Index",
                    dataProvider: app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<CategoryCachedRouteDataProvider>(),
                    cache: app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>(),
                    target: routes.DefaultHandler)
                {
                    CacheTimeoutInSeconds = 900
                });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Note that the `CachedRoute<TPrimaryKey>` can be reused to create additional routes for other tables. So, if you wanted to, you could also make your product URLs like `guitars/acoustic-guitars/some-fancy-acoustic-guitar` by using a join on the Category table and using a similar method to build the URL.

The URLs can be generated and added to the UI using [Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/) or any of the other `UrlHelper` based methods. For example:

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="12">Effects</a>
```

Which is generated as

```
<a href="/amps-and-effects/effects">Effects</a>
```

You can of course then use the primary key of the model to generate the URL and the text for the link - it is all automatic and straightforward using models that have the primary key and name.

The only thing extra you would need to do is to create the hierarchy for the link display. But that is outside of the scope of routing.

Note that there is no concept of hierarchy at all in routing - it is simply a list of routes that is matched from top to bottom on each request.

> If the routing template is set up to support that, how to retrieve the leaf category? For example, from the URL /guitars/acoustic-guitars, I would like to retrieve acoustic-guitars as the leaf category, and able to get all products under that acoustic-guitars category. Note: I don't want manual parsing on the URL. Ideally it would be the best if the lead category is binded through model binding.

It is unclear why you would need a "leaf category" as this has nothing to do with incoming or outgoing routes, nor is it required to lookup the database data. Again, the primary key is all you need to generate the entire URL based on routing and it should be all that is required to view all of the products. But if you really need access to it you can look it up in your controller.

### Customization

You may need to change the caching strategy depending on your specific requirements.

1. You may wish to use an LRU cache strategy with a fixed maximum number of links in RAM
2. You may wish to track how often the URLs are being hit and move the most frequently visited URLs to the top of the list
3. You may wish to share the cache between the routes and your update action methods so when URLs are successfully updated in the database, they are also updated in the cache at the same time for "real-time" URLs
4. You may wish to cache each URL individually and look them up one at a time instead of caching the whole list in one go

Comment: hmmm creating a customized `IRouter` implementation is new to me. Let me try and see if it works out on my app and I will mark it as answer. Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/davidliang2008/CategorySystem is the Github repo of the demo project I am trying to build to test this concept. Stay tuned.

Comment: I have to make the scope of `AppDbContext` Singleton in order to inject that  into `CategoryCachedRouteDataProvider` because `CategoryCachedRouteDataProvider` is injected as a Singleton. Anyway your approach is interesting and works nicely! Thanks a lot for the time. I am still trying to think if there is a cleaner way to do it without using cache.

Comment: You definitely need to cache for at least a second or two. Routes are run on *every request* and also once for each URL that is generated. It could easily overload a database to run that many queries and cause a DOS. However, as I mentioned there is no reason why the cache couldn't be changed to suit a specific purpose depending on scalability or refresh requirements.