# Valid Action treating as slug and keeps redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have tried to implement slug url like this

> www.abcd.com/xyz/er/productname

where "/xyx/er" is area and it's working, But when ever I am trying to go to another page like

> www.abcd.com/xyz/er/Login

then it's just keep redirecting.

Here is my code for RegisterArea:

```
 context.MapRoute(
                name: "product",
                url: "xyz/er/{*slug}",
                defaults: new { controller = "er", action = "Index", slug = UrlParameter.Optional }
                 );

context.MapRoute(
                "default",
                "xyz/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller="er", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

            );
```

and my controller code is:

```
public ActionResult Index(string slug=null)
{
    if (slug != null && (slug != "Index" && slug != "index"))
    {
        //it will show the product
    }
    else
    {
        //redirect to another page
    }
}
```

Comment: here slug get replaced by whatever you type after `er/` (other then index)  and redirect to `er/index` and  //it will show the product

Comment: Because `www.abcd.com/xyz/er/Login` hits you first route definition and goes to the `Index()` method which will try to display a product named `Login`

Comment: I am not sure if this work, try change your url into `url: "xyz/er/Index/{*slug}"` and your url will look like `www.abcd.com/xyz/er/Index/productname`. and in other case `www.abcd.com/xyz/er/Login`.

Comment: i have tried with  url: "xyz/er/Index/{*slug}" it's working but I don't want this type of url, I want url: "xyx/er/{*slug}". @ashik

Comment: If that's the case then you need to create specific routes for all the other methods (e.g. `url "xyz/erLogin"` and locate them before the `product` route

Comment: Or you would need a route constraint that checks if `slug` is a product name, and if not return false so that it falls through to the new route (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358416/routing-in-asp-net-mvc-showing-username-in-url/37359345#37359345) for an example)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried previously with constraint but not this way. @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

with the help of Stephen's comment, I implemented a constraint for checking my product name. If Product name is valid it will show the intended page and if not found then it will redirect to Login page.

The code is given below:

```
    context.MapRoute(
                    name: "product",
                    url: "xyz/er/{*slug}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "er", action = "Index", slug = UrlParameter.Optional },
 constraints: new { productname= new ProductNameConstraint() }
                     );


public class ProductNameConstraint: IRouteConstraint
        {
            public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
            {
                //logic here
            }
        }
```