# How to choose a controller and view dynamically from a route segment in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a route url like `http://localhost/p201/info` for which I want to choose the controller `ProductController`. For `http://localhost/p1201/info` also, I want the same `ProductController`.

For a route like `http://localhost/c301/info`, I want to select the `CategoryController`.

I have a key-value dictionary in the app to choose the controller for a segment:

`segment - controller
p201 - ProductController
p1201 - ProductController
c301 - CategoryController`

What route extension I have to implement to dynamically select the controller from the key-value dictionary for a segment name and invoke the controller method?

Comment: Do you literally have an `IDictionary<T>` somwehere which maps those values?

Comment: Yes. That list is managed in the database, and read into cache in ```startup.cs``` file as a dictionary.

Comment: Have you considered using attribute routing

Comment: I don't know what to specify in the attribute to say the controller maps to ```p201, p1201, c301``` etc... There can be many such segments.

Comment: How many different controllers do you have? If its only a small number, you could use a `RouteConstraint` (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358416/routing-in-asp-net-mvc-showing-username-in-url/37359345#37359345) for an example